# Find the row in one table using another table column data

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables `tab1` and `tab2`. `tab1` has 39000 records and `tab2` has 15000 records. `tab1` and `tab2` both have two common columns say `item_number`, `color_code`. But in `tab1`,  `color_code` may be null but not in `tab2`. `item_number` is not null in both tables. In `tab2` I have to insert a row (unique row based on two columns) data from `tab1`. For this I have written a procedure like this. It will compare each row but it is taking too long. Is there any way to improve performance. Taking two cursors first:

```
CURSOR CUR_tab1 IS SELECT item_number,color_code FROM 
    (SELECT item_number,color_code, SNO RID ,
         MIN(SNO) OVER(partition BY item_number,color_code)
         MIN_RID FROM   tab1  ) WHERE RID= MIN_RID;

CURSOR CUR_tab2 IS SELECT sno_2,item_number,color_code,PRIORITY FROM tab2;
```

`son`, `sno_2` are primary keys in `tab1` and `tab2`.

To find the records in one table I am using a `for loop`.

```
SELECT NVL(MAX(SNO_2),0) INTO SNO_COUNT FROM tab2;
FOR CUR_tab1  IN CUR_NIIN_CAGE
LOOP
    -- GET THE NIIN_CAGE_PART RECORDS DATA.
    OLD_NNCGP_NIIN := CUR_tab1 .item_number;
    OLD_NNCGP_HCC  := CUR_tab1 .color_codeC;

    IF (SNO_COUNT>0 AND OLD_NNCGP_HCC IS NOT NULL) THEN  -- IF RECORDS EXISTS IN DB  
        FOR CUR_tab2 IN CUR_NIIN_HCC
        LOOP
            OLD_NIIN        := CUR_tab2.item_number;
            OLD_HCC         := CUR_tab2.color_codeC;
            NIIN_PRIORITY   := CUR_tab2.PRIORITY;

            IF (trim(OLD_NNCGP_NIIN) = trim(OLD_NIIN)
                AND trim(OLD_NNCGP_HCC)=trim(OLD_HCC)) THEN
                -- DO NOTHING
                ROW_COUNT:=0;
                PROCESSED   :=FALSE;
                EXIT;
            ELSE
                ROW_COUNT:=ROW_COUNT+1;
                PROCESSED   :=TRUE;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    ELSIF (SNO_COUNT=0 AND OLD_NNCGP_HCC IS NOT NULL) THEN
         PROCESSED   :=TRUE;
         ROW_COUNT:=ROW_COUNT+1;                  
    END IF;  

    IF (  PROCESSED ) THEN
        SNO_COUNT :=SNO_COUNT+1;   
        INSERT INTO tab2("SNO2","color_code","item_number","PRIORITY") 
        values (SNO_COUNT,OLD_NNCGP_HCC,OLD_NNCGP_NIIN,NULL);
        COMMIT;
    END IF;

    PROCESSED:=FALSE;
    ROW_COUNT:=0;
END LOOP;
```

But this is taking nearly 7 minutes. Is there any better way to compare the columns?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve. the normal method of ensuring uniqueness of a row, based on one or more column values is to create a unique index.

```
alter table <table>
  add constraint <constraint_name> unique (<column1>,..,<column_n>);
```

Whenever you try to insert a record with a combination of column values that already exists in the table an exception will be raised (DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX).

Comment: i want to compare two columns in one table with other table. If not found insert them. if found update third column value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code inserts records on a Row By Agonising Row basis.  That's why it is slow.  SQL is a set -based language.  So embrace the Joy Of Sets and see your performance increase.

Unfortunately you haven't posted your whole code example, so the following is likely to be wrong in the specifics but it should show your the right idea:

```
    SELECT NVL(MAX(SNO_2),0) INTO SNO_COUNT FROM tab2;        

    INSERT INTO tab2("SNO2","color_code","item_number","PRIORITY")  
        select SNO_COUNT+rownum,tab1.color_codeC,tab1.item_number,NULL)
        from 
        ( select distinct tab1.color_codeC,tab1.item_number
          from tab1
          where not exists
             ( select null from tab2
               where trim(tab1."color_codeC") = trim(tab2."color_codeC")
               and trim(tab1."item_number") = trim(tab2."item_number") )
```

---

There are a couple of things which are bad about your data model.

1. Using MAX(SNO_COUNT).  This technique does not scale and does not work in multi-user environments.  You should use an Oracle Sequence instead.
2. Using double-quoted mixed case identifiers.  This is just a series of ORA-00904 bugs waiting to happen.  Just use upper-case identifiers and forget about the double-quotes.

Comment: i want to compare two columns in one table with other table. If not found insert them. But the 2 columns in tab2 are unique and in tab1  item_number is not null but color_code is null allowed column. so tab1 has more than one combination of  item_number ,color_code.

Comment: @mallikarjun - in these situations it is better if you explain your business logic rather than presenting your code (or, even worse, part of your code, as you did) and expecting us to figure it out.  Anyway, I have revised my guess so gave it a whirl.